# How to use conditions in SoapUI (not pro)?

Tags: soapui

The steps in the test suite are:

1. Add function.
2. Use Response of Add function in Divide function with Property Transfer.
3. Increment value if response is less than 15.

I want to use conditional Go to option to do this. How can I achieve this with the **free** version of *SoapUI*?

Comment: Switch to Java or any programming language and you won't need to pay for anything ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can "cheat it" by using a groovy script to perform your conditional go to

Assuming you put your values into properties called Properties;

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner

String incrementvalue = context.expand( '${Properties#incrementvalue}' );
//convert to int as properties are strings by default
int convertedincrementvalue = Integer.parseInt(incrementvalue);

if(convertedincrementvalue < 15)
testRunner.gotoStepByName(["The name of the step you want to go to"])
else
log.info("Continued")
```